# Android Studio startActvity requires permission

Tags: java, android, android-studio, start-activity

I'm attempting to make a simple click action which calls a certain number, I'm on the last stage of the code and I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. Currently its the startActivity action which seems to be presenting the error but I don't know why I have watched multiple tutorials and I can see any difference. When above startActivity it informs me that a call permission is required?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    //On load the program automatically hides the taskbar.

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


    Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.BTNCall);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent PhoneCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            PhoneCall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123"));
            startActivity(PhoneCall);
        }



    });


}
```

I have also added a permission into the android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: when present in my code the startActivity is the error, its highlighted red

Comment: The code seems to be working fine on my device. Can you may be run `gradle clean assemble` from command line and see if you get any errors?

Comment: Just retested still no difference so I opened a next project and chucked it in and works perfectly seem like its time to go fault finding.

Comment: Just a follow up but I know longer have the errors but just to annoy me its informs me that it unexpectedly stops when I try to press the button.

Comment: if you are targeting M, and the permission has not been granted (and apparently you don't ask for it), it will throw a security exception, which you should catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your target SDK version to lvl 22 or under, because for lvl 23 you need to ask user at run time for permission, look [there](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks perfect answer

Answer (score -1):

Since you are doing it from a OnClickListener, the "this" pointer references to the clickListener class you are implementing, you need to get the reference to your activity just use:

```
MyActivityClassName.this.startActivity() //Dont know your class name
```

That should get rid of the red highlight.

If you are still getting a crash we will need the logcat output to solve it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope, method resolution for non-static inner classes resolve outer class method too.

Comment: Your are right, never tried it, but what i said about the "this" pointer its still true. I´ve always thought it was already using "this" when you dont specify an object.